# Keeping the child route same on click of the parent route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have two parent routes `/home` and `/app`.

Within `/app` there are two more nested routes. `/app/first` and `/app/second`

```
--/home

--/app
  --/app/first
  --/app/second
```

I have set links on home page to route within `/home` and `/app`.

When I click on the `/app` I wish to redirect the user to `/app/first`, which I have achieved using the `Redirect` component and it works fine but only on the first click.
When I click on `/app` route again it doesn't redirect to `/app/first` again rather it fallbacks to `/app`

How do I keep routing to `/app/first` every time I click on the `/app` link even if I am already on `/app`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-router-demo-nqwqf) is a sandbox for this issue.

Comment: Did you tried `<Route path="/app" component={First} />` if your goal is to render First

Comment: @techipank yes I did, but I want the route to change too. your method will keep the path to ```/app``` and render the first component. I wish to have ```/app/first``` and then only render the first component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/app" render={() => <Redirect to="/app/first"/>}/>
      <Route path="/app/first" component={First} />
      <Route path="/app/second" component={Second} />
</Switch>
```

in your app.js file.

So what you want is the default "/app" route to render the {first} component AND show "/app/first" in the browser path? Yes?

Comment: This works, but the page refreshes everytime I click on the same link. Whereas, earlier it wasn't the case.

Comment: Try using the location prop that is passed to your route, https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location. So something like, <Route path='/app' render={ ({location}) => location.<some_property> === '/app' ? null : <App /> }/>